# Computer algebra system for Weyl algebra computations

Tags: computer-algebra, weyl-algebra

Does anyone have a suggestion for the best computer program to perform calculations in the 2nd Weyl algebra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weyl algebra computations are implemented in
[Macaulay 2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.8.2/share/doc/Macaulay2/Dmodules/html/) (package D-modules). Here is a [manual.](http://www.math.kobe-u.ac.jp/~taka/2007/knx/leykin-2002-m2.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

I use GAP (http://www.gap-system.org/) with the GBNP package (http://www.win.tue.nl/~amc/pub/grobner/chap0.html).
You define Weyl algebra as a quotient of free associative algebra by the ideal
$<x_1 x_2 - x_2 x_1 - 1>$.
Easy to generalize to arbitrary dimension and can handle Clifford algebras
(of arbitrary signatures) in the same setting.

Answer (score 3):

[Singular](http://www.singular.uni-kl.de/) claims to be wise in the ways of Weyl algebra.

Comment: Have you used singular? I have been trying to install and I am struggling.

Comment: Struggling in what way? Where are you installing it?

Comment: I have followed the GUIDED CYGWIN INSTALL instructions on the site you linked. The mirror they suggest doesn't seem to up anymore. I have tried other mirrors but in the end when I try to run Singular out of the Cygwin window I just get error messages.

Comment: If you install Sage, you get a copy of Singular included with it, and the Sage install process is quite carefully tested on a wide range of platforms, so it's possible that this may be easier than installing Singular alone.

Comment: you can run singular on cloud.sagemath.com